# Why pytorch isn't minimizing x*x for me?

Tags: python, optimization, pytorch, tensor

I expect x to converge to 0, which is minimum of x*x. But this doesn't happen. What am I doing wrong in this small sample code:

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
tns = torch.FloatTensor([3])
x = Variable(tns, requires_grad=True)
z = x*x
opt = torch.optim.Adam([x], lr=.01, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
for i in range(3000):
    z.backward(retain_graph=True) # Calculate gradients
    opt.step()
    print(x)
```

Comment: Can you show the output? What's actually happening to x?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you have is that you don't zero the gradients when you are calculating each loop. Instead, by setting `retain_graph=True` and not calling `opt.zero_grad()` at each step of the loop you are actually adding the gradients calculated to **ALL** previous gradients calculated. So instead of taking a step in gradient descent, you are taking a step with respect to **all** accumulated gradients which is certainly NOT what you want.

You should instead make sure to call `opt.zero_grad()` at the beginning of your loop, and move the `z=x*x` inside your loop so that you don't have to `retain_graph`.

I made these slight modifications:

```
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable
tns = torch.FloatTensor([3])
x = Variable(tns, requires_grad=True)
opt = torch.optim.Adam([x], lr=.01, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
for i in range(3000):
    opt.zero_grad()
    z = x*x
    z.backward() # Calculate gradients
    opt.step()
    print(x)
```

And my final `x` is `1e-25`.