# pytorch optimizer tracing fails miserably

Tags: python, pytorch

Consider the following piece of code:

```
tns = torch.FloatTensor([3])
x = Variable(tns, requires_grad=True)
opt = torch.optim.Adam([x], lr=.01, betas=(0.5, 0.999))
xes = [x]
for i in range(10):
    opt.zero_grad()
    z = x*x
    z.backward() # Calculate gradients
    opt.step()
    xes.append(x)
    print(x)
```

(this is stolen essentially verbatim from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50588958/why-pytorch-isnt-minimizing-xx-for-me). Now, the code works fine, as far as the optimization goes, and here is what it prints:

```
tensor([2.9900], requires_grad=True)
tensor([2.9800], requires_grad=True)
tensor([2.9700], requires_grad=True)
tensor([2.9600], requires_grad=True)
tensor([2.9501], requires_grad=True)
tensor([2.9401], requires_grad=True)
tensor([2.9302], requires_grad=True)
tensor([2.9203], requires_grad=True)
tensor([2.9104], requires_grad=True)
tensor([2.9005], requires_grad=True)
```

That's the good news. The bad news is that this is the array `xes`:

```
[tensor([2.9005], requires_grad=True),
 tensor([2.9005], requires_grad=True),
 tensor([2.9005], requires_grad=True),
 tensor([2.9005], requires_grad=True),
 tensor([2.9005], requires_grad=True),
 tensor([2.9005], requires_grad=True),
 tensor([2.9005], requires_grad=True),
 tensor([2.9005], requires_grad=True),
 tensor([2.9005], requires_grad=True),
 tensor([2.9005], requires_grad=True),
 tensor([2.9005], requires_grad=True)]
```

Which is **not** what I expected. So, there are two questions:

The first is: why is this not working, and how to make it work.

The second is: is there some canonical way of optimizer tracing?

Comment: Variables in python are references. You are storing many copies of the same reference (variable `x`) in your array. The memory is modified in place by the optimizer so you need to create copies if you want them to be different later. Something like `xes.append(x.clone())` should work.

Comment: @jodag I figured they were references, but could not find any way around it! thanks!